# Move the table right to align with my texts in Outlook body

Tags: html, vba, outlook

I am trying to sent an email from outlook using Excel Macro and I need a solution on how I can move the tables I copy paste from the Excel to Outlook body, which will always get aligned to left side, and I want it to be moved to little right so that I will get a perfectly fit/alignment with the other contents I have on the top.

*My Code*

```
   Sub Table_CopyPaste()

        Dim outlook As Object 
        Dim newEmail As Object 
        Dim xInspect As Object 
        Dim pageEditor As Object

            Set outlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application") Set newEmail = outlook.CreateItem(0)

StrBody1 = "<o:p>&nbsp;</o:p><p class=MsoNormal><span lang=EN-US style='color:#1F497D'><span style='font:11.0pt 'Calibri'>Hello,</Span></p><p class=MsoNormal><span style='font:11.0pt 'Calibri(Body)'>Attached you can find a file with all your Status for month 10_2019. </p></span><p class=MsoNormal><span style='font:11.0pt 'Calibri(Body)'>Below you can find an overview of your current status and your unit status.</span></span></p>" _ 
& "<p class=MsoListParagraph style='margin-left:53.4pt;text-indent:-18.0pt;mso-list:l0 level1 lfo2'><span style='font:11.0pt 'Calibri'><span lang=EN-US style='color:#1F497D'>1) &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; We have extended the report with additional information, so you can develop a more complete view on your status:" _ 
& "<br>" _ 
& "<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;- &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp HR" _ 
& "<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;- &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp Accounts" _ 
& "<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;- &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp Finance" _


            With newEmail
                .To = "Test@mail.com"
                .CC = ""
                .BCC = ""
                .Subject = "Data"
                .HTMLBody = StrBody1
                .Display

                Set xInspect = newEmail.GetInspector
                Set pageEditor = xInspect.WordEditor

                Sheets("Statistics_Sheet").Range("A3:D6").Copy

                pageEditor.Application.Selection.Start = Len(.HTMLBody)
                pageEditor.Application.Selection.End = pageEditor.Application.Selection.Start

                pageEditor.Application.Selection.PasteAndFormat (wdFormatPlainText)
                .Display
                '.Send
                Set pageEditor = Nothing
                Set xInspect = Nothing End With

            Set newEmail = Nothing Set outlook = Nothing

            End Sub
```

This is the first time I am working on integrating outlook with macro, so no much idea how to solve this. The code is working fine once we run this code I need the table to be placed aligned with the bullet point 'Finance'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After too many search here and there, I find that its not possible to move it but a workaround here is to add some extra blank cells in that range so that when it copy pasted to outlook you will get it aligned to the text (Adjust the width of the cells to change the alignment)

But I find a code which work like a charm,

```
Sub PublishTable()

Dim WB As ThisWorkbook, P As String, WS As Worksheet, Rng As Range, New_WB As Workbook, RNG2 As Range, FolderPath As String
Set WB = ThisWorkbook
Set WS = WB.Sheets("Statistics_Sheet")

FolderPath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path
Set Rng = Sheets("Statistics_Sheet").Range("C3:F6")
P = FolderPath & "\Calculation_of_exception_status.html"

Workbooks.Add
Set New_WB = ActiveWorkbook
ThisWorkbook.Activate
Rng.Copy

New_WB.Activate
ActiveCell.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
ActiveCell.PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
ActiveCell.PasteSpecial xlPasteColumnWidths
ActiveCell.PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats

New_WB.PublishObjects.Add(xlSourceRange, P, New_WB.Sheets(1).Name, New_WB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Address, xlHtmlStatic).Publish (True)
ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False

Dim fso As New FileSystemObject
Set fso = New Scripting.FileSystemObject

Dim Final_File As Scripting.TextStream
Set Final_File = fso.OpenTextFile(P, ForReading)
StrTable2 = Final_File.ReadAll

End Sub
```

And when you use Strtable2 in your outlook body use below code, adjust '20.3pt' according to your requirement.

```
olMailItm.HTMLBody = "<table class=MsoNormalTable border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 style='margin-left:20.3pt;border-collapse:collapse'>" & StrTable2 & "</Table>"
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's an actual HTML `<table>` element that it inserts, you can add a stylesheet to the `.HTMLBody`

At the top, `Dim` a variable:

```
Dim sStyles As String
sStyles = "<style> table {margin-left:150px;} table table {margin-left:0px;} </style><br>"
```

And then where you set the `.HTMLBody`, add it in like this:

```
.HTMLBody = sStyles & StrBody1
```

Then adjust the `150` number in the code to whatever you want to get it to align where you want it.

Comment: Thanks you for your time,Sorry but the table is not HTML <table>, its actually copy pasted from an excel sheet. Data inside the table keep changing so before I run this macro there are some other macro repopulate the table data each time. If you think still the above code works, please tell me know, how to apply it to my piece of code. Thank you

Comment: If it's not an html table, then what is it? If it's coming from Excel, then I'm quite sure it's an html table. You can at least try the code out, to see if it works, and take it out if it doesnt work, right?

Comment: Thanks braX, but will you guide me where should I put the 'sStyles =' Tag in my code ?

Comment: Try this instead then: https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/bmail2.htm

Comment: Thank you braX, I solved my issue in a different way, thanks for your help and support.

Comment: @Brax " brax" I also tried your answer , but it doesn't work

Comment: Then your scenario must be different, or you did something wrong. But just posting a "it didn't work" comment is not helpful to anyone.